# Is there a Gnuplot GUI?

Tags: 10.10

Is there a Gnuplot GUI (equivalent to wgnuplot.exe) for Ubuntu ?

Comment: how about texmacs?

Answer (score 3):

I found this two.

http://linux.softpedia.com/downloadTag/Gnuplot+GUI

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jgp/

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there was identical tool for linux. The Java Gnuplot GUI is the closest so far.

Comment: You need that for statistics? if yes ask to: http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: also have a look at kayali.

http://kayali.sourceforge.net/index.html#overview